# Combinations Math - Choosing from juries

Tags: probability, combinations

This is a question I have on my assignment and I’m having difficulties figuring it out. It involves combinations and probability.

Suppose there are $4$ different jury rooms, each seating $7$ men and $8$ women. A jury consists of $6$ people.

What is the probability that you select a jury with $4$ men in one room and a jury with $3$ women from another room?

Comment: I do not understand the statement of the problem...

Comment: Neither do I. Are you selecting one jury from the total of the men and women in the $4$ rooms combined. How many men are there and how many women. What is the mechanism for making the selections.

Comment: I forgot to indicate the number of women. I have 7 men and 8 women - 15 people in each room, therefore 60 people in total.

Comment: Did you mean a jury consists of $7$ people?  Otherwise, why are $4$ men and $3$ women selected for the jury?

Comment: Please edit or rewrite your question so it makes sense. Updates by comments can just add to the confusion.

Comment: One jury will consist of 4 men, and another jury will consist of 3 women. Then the other two juries will follow. The 4 men are in a separate room from the 3 women. Each jury room can have 6 people, so altogether there is 24 people for the 4 juries. 6 x 4 = 24 people

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{60}{7}$ ways to choose $7$ people from $60$.

Choosing $4$ men from a room say room A, is $\binom{8}{4}$ and $3$ from other three rooms, each gives $\binom{7}{3} $ways to choose. This is $3* \binom{7}{3}$ (added for each room)

Now, since we have $4$ rooms for men, so by symmetry, the total favourable cases are :

$$4* (\binom{8}{4} * ( 3 * \binom{7}{3} ) ) $$

Therefore, the probability is

$$
\frac{29400}{386206920}\approx 7.612*10^{-5}$$